# What is the theoretical maximum Attack Damage you can get?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was just wondering, what is the maximum Attack Damage you can get on a character if you picked the one with the highest based damage at lvl 18 and just stacked AD on them? I guess this would be the ultimate glass cannon :P.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_damage#Trivia

> Besides Sion with  Atma's Impaler (due to his Enrage), the maximum attack damage any champion can get at level 18 is 1364, being Malphite with Brutal Strikes active, all Might runes and the Brute Force and Summoner's Wrath masteries with Ignite on cooldown, a fully stacked  Sword of the Occult and 5 other fully stacked  Bloodthirsters, while having the Exalted with Baron Nashor,  Aegis of the Legion, Raise Morale, Eye of the Storm, Radiance, Hymn of Valor and  Elixir of Fortitude buffs.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is no longer accurate due to item and champion changes.

Answer (score 0):

http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=237325. technically no there is not an AD cap but since there is a cap on how many items you can buy it is sort of capped i guess.